# Conductor ideal and dual lattice

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $A$ be Dedekind domain, $K$ be the field of fraction of $A$. Let $L$ be a finite separable extension of $K$, then $T(x,y)=Tr(xy)$ is an non-degenerate bilinear form. Then let $X$ be a $A$-submodule of $L$, we say $X$ is a lattice if $X$ is finitely generated and span $L$ using $K$-coefficients.

In particular, $B$ is a lattice of $A$ over $L$ where $B$ is the integral closure over $A$ of $L$. Next, we define dual lattice of any lattice $X$ to be $X^*:=\{x\in L:\forall y\in X, Tr(xy)\in A\}$.

Let $C$ be a subring of $B$ that contains $A$, then we define the conductor to be $f:=\{x\in C: xB\subseteq C\}$. Then the question is to show that we have $$f_{C/B}=(B^*:C^*):=\{x\in L: xC^*\subseteq B^*\}$$

Attempt:

If $x\in f_{C/B}\subseteq C$ then $xC^*\subseteq B^*$. Indeed, let $c\in C^*$ then for all $b\in B$ we have $xcb=(xb)\cdot c$ with $xb\in C$ and hence $Tr(xcb)\in A$ as $c\in C^*$. This shows $f_{C/B}\subseteq (B^*:C^*)$. On the other hand, observe $x\in (B^*:C^*)$ then we have $B^*\subseteq C^*$ so $xB^*\subseteq xC^*$. Together with $xC^*\subseteq B$ we have $xB^*\subseteq B^*$ and hence $x\subseteq B$.

Next, if I can show $x$ is actually inside $C$ then the proof would follow. However, I'm not sure how to continue from here. It would suffice to show $xB^*\subseteq C$ as $1\in B^*$ but even that seems confusing to me as the trace condition seems really hard to use.

Comment: Are you sure this is true? I can think of a proof for $C$ of a special form but not in general.

Comment: @TokenToucan I computed it for $L=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and $C=\mathbb{Z}[2]$ and it is true... However I also wonder if it is true or not since the conductor is normally defined as $f:=\{x\in L: xC\subseteq B\}$ where $C$ is an order. It is an exercise from Serre's local field.

Comment: Not sure if we can do this or not. However, there does exist a relation for dual lattice which is $X\subseteq Y$ then $Y^*\subseteq X^*$ and vice versa. In particular, we also have $(aX)^*=\frac{1}{a}X^*$ for $a$ invertible. Thus can we just say $xC^*\subseteq B^*$ imply $B\subseteq (1/x)C$ and hence $xB\subseteq C$ as desired?

Comment: Where is the exercise in Serre? The issue with your second argument is that it's not always true that taking the trace dual twice gives back the original.

Comment: @TokenToucan   Chapter 3, Section 4, page 53, second edition in English.

Comment: Huh. Well maybe I am making a mistake. I didn't think that the formula in (c) of that exercise was true in general but I could be wrong. I have a proof for $C = A[\alpha]$ because there one can use the dual basis.

Comment: I thought that the double dual formula holds for all lattices, isn't it? Could you give some examples of where this fails?